# Open source replacement for Google Play location services on Android

Tags: android, gps, location, google-play-services

Is there a open source replacement for Google Play location services that nicely integrates all the different Android location providers into a simple interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but this library seems to do what you're looking for:

[lostzen/LOST](https://github.com/lostzen/LOST)

Comment: Yeah I found this last month. I am now using it and it is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

And what about [microg](https://microg.org/) project?